# extract key parts a string where the content is enclosed in a <b> tag

Tags: python

from a web request I get this answer:

```
    <table>

    <tr>


    <td style="font-size:110%;color:blue;font-weight:bold">quiero</td>

    <td style="font-style:italic;">categoría&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>AUX</b></td>


    <td style="font-style:italic;">lema&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>QUERER</b></td>


    <td style="font-style:italic;">rasgos&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>&nbsp;singular&nbsp;&nbsp;1&nbsp;&nbsp;presente indicativo&nbsp;</b></td>


    </tr>


    <tr>


    <td style="font-size:110%;color:blue;font-weight:bold">ser</td>

    <td style="font-style:italic;">categoría&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>V</b></td>


    <td style="font-style:italic;">lema&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>SER</b></td>


    <td style="font-style:italic;">rasgos&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>&nbsp;infinitivo&nbsp;</b></td>


    </tr>


    <tr>


    <td style="font-size:110%;color:blue;font-weight:bold">el</td>

    <td style="font-style:italic;">categoría&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>ART</b></td>

    <td style="font-style:italic;">lema&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>EL</b></td>


    <td style="font-style:italic;">rasgos&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>&nbsp;masculino&nbsp;&nbsp;singular&nbsp;</b></td>


    </tr>


    <tr>


    <td style="font-size:110%;color:blue;font-weight:bold">mejor</td>

    <td style="font-style:italic;">categoría&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>ADJ</b></td>


    <td style="font-style:italic;">lema&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>MEJOR</b></td>


    <td style="font-style:italic;">rasgos&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>&nbsp;singular&nbsp;</b></td>


    </tr>


    </table>
```

but I'm interested in only getting everything that is inside the `<b>` tag. Is there an optimal way to do it? in my knowledge, I could only achieve it using `.split` but I do not think it's a very elegant or very optimal way to achieve it

This is my desired output:

```
v
SER
&nbsp;infinitivo&nbsp;
ART
El
&nbsp;masculino&nbsp;&nbsp;singular&nbsp;
.
.
.
```

this is my string response of the request

Comment: You are correct. Parsing HTML using string operations like `split()` is not the best approach. Have a look at the module BeautifulSoup https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/ .

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`html.parser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html)

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser

class BExtractor(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BExtractor, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.is_b = True

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if tag == "b":
            self.is_b = True

    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
            self.is_b = False

    def handle_data(self, data):
        if self.is_b:
            print(data)

parser = BExtractor()
parser.feed("""html""")
```

Comment: thanks, genious! Sorry, I'm new to python I do not know how to test your code, can you do something to avoid defining BExtractor class, something like doing it in a function?

Comment: The HTMLParser of python only works as a Class. You could write a function that uses the Parser to extract the data and then returns it as a list. To test it, just copy the code and execute it with python3. For python2 `import from HTMLParser import HTMLParser` instead

Comment: thanks for you answer I have a .py file, in the same file I define the class? I have another question, the variable that has the string is called "stringHtml" so to get the answer I must execute parser.feed (stringHtml)?

Comment: replace """html""" with your string. Yes you can define the class in the same file

Comment: I have a new problem, can you give a hand please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55212392/extract-key-parts-a-string-where-the-content-is-enclosed-in-a-span-style-font?noredirect=1#comment97160708_55212392